# Bootstrap: Use .pull-right without having to hardcode a negative margin-top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code (please see fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/SyjjW/)):

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='hero-unit'>
        <h2>Welcome</h2>

        <p>Please log in</p>
        <div id='login-box' class='pull-right control-group'>
            <div class='clearfix'>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Username' />
            </div>
            <div class='clearfix'>
                <input type='password' placeholder='Password' />
            </div>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Log in</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want `#login-box` to have `.pull-right` and be at the same height as the `p`. I can use `margin-top: -100px` but that feels wrong.

How can I have `#login-box` at the same height as the `p` without hardcoding a negative `margin-top`?

Comment: Simply remove the two `class='clearfix'` that you have, since they don't do anything there, and change `class='hero-unit'` to `class='hero-unit clearfix'` instead.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Float elements will be rendered at the line they are normally in the layout. To fix this, you have two choices:

Move the header and the p after the login box:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='hero-unit'>

        <div id='login-box' class='pull-right control-group'>
            <div class='clearfix'>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Username' />
            </div>
            <div class='clearfix'>
                <input type='password' placeholder='Password' />
            </div>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Log in</button>
        </div>

        <h2>Welcome</h2>

        <p>Please log in</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

Or enclose the left block in a pull-left div, and add a clearfix at the bottom

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='hero-unit'>

        <div class="pull-left">

          <h2>Welcome</h2>

          <p>Please log in</p>

        </div>

        <div id='login-box' class='pull-right control-group'>
            <div class='clearfix'>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Username' />
            </div>
            <div class='clearfix'>
                <input type='password' placeholder='Password' />
            </div>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Log in</button>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

just put `#login-box` before `<h2>Welcome</h2>` will be ok.

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='hero-unit'>
        <div id='login-box' class='pull-right control-group'>
            <div class='clearfix'>
                <input type='text' placeholder='Username' />
            </div>
            <div class='clearfix'>
                <input type='password' placeholder='Password' />
            </div>
            <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Log in</button>
        </div>
        <h2>Welcome</h2>

        <p>Please log in</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

here is jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/SyjjW/4/

Answer (score 0):

Keep the h2 at the top, then pull-left on the p and pull-right on the login-box

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class='hero-unit'>

    <h2>Welcome</h2>

    <div class="pull-left">
      <p>Please log in</p>
    </div>

    <div id='login-box' class='pull-right control-group'>
        <div class='clearfix'>
            <input type='text' placeholder='Username' />
        </div>
        <div class='clearfix'>
            <input type='password' placeholder='Password' />
        </div>
        <button type='button' class='btn btn-primary'>Log in</button>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

  </div>
</div>
```

the default vertical-align on floated boxes is baseline, so the "Please log in" exactly lines up with the "Username" (check by changing the pull-right to pull-left).