# CSS alignment issue of textbox and button in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm newbie in Angular and trying to develop my first application but stuck in alignment using bootstrap classes.

Here is my Code:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label>Client</label>
    <Select class="form-control">
      <option>Client 1</option>
      <option>Client 2</option>
      <option>Client 3</option>
      <option>Client 4</option>
      <option>Client 5</option>
      <option>Client 6</option>
    </Select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <button type=submit class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Add</button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info pull-right" vertical-align="bottom"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Get Data</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here the output of this code

[image]

Problem is that all these inputs are top-aligned but I want client dropdown and both buttons to be bottom aligned.

I tried `input-group-btn` class but that didn't work for me. Even here on StackOverflow, I found solutions only about right-alignment.

Comment: what do you mean by "top-aligned"? how do you exactly want it to be?

Comment: @Roysh I want Add button aligned with client dropdown not with client label as it is right now

Comment: Got it. Well the easiest and ugliest solution is to add some padding/margin to the the buttons and align them with the input.
Otherwise, try to take the label tag out of the row.
Btw, can you try to upload a fiddle?

Comment: I tried margin/ padding and it worked for me but that's not a good solution. Isn't there something like pull-right?

Comment: And in case of Label, empty label does not work and a label with content is useless for me

Comment: try to look here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14416563/bootstrap-use-pull-right-without-having-to-hardcode-a-negative-margin-top
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19404861/bootstrap-3-pull-right-for-col-lg-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`div inside div` resolved my problem.. here is my code

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <div class="row">
     <div class="col-md-12">
          <label >Client</label>
          <div class="row">
               <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                     <Select class="form-control" >
                           <option>Client 1</option>
                           <option>Client 2</option>
                           <option>Client 3</option>
                           <option>Client 4</option>
                           <option>Client 5</option>
                           <option>Client 6</option>
                          </Select>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                             <button type=submit class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Add </button>
                         </div>
                         <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info pull-right" vertical-align="bottom"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>  Get Data </button> 
                          </div>
                      </div>

              </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

try this code, i am not sure but `<label >&nbsp;</label>`this should work to align them in one line.

update this css

```
<style>    
   label {
        width: 100%;
    }
</style>
```

```css
label {
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
        <label >Client</label>
        <Select class="form-control" >
          <option>Client 1</option>
          <option>Client 2</option>
          <option>Client 3</option>
          <option>Client 4</option>
          <option>Client 5</option>
          <option>Client 6</option>
        </Select>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label >&nbsp;</label>
        <button type=submit class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Add </button>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label >&nbsp;</label>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info pull-right" vertical-align="bottom"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>  Get Data </button> 
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: agree with Roysh please create a codepen @NullPointer

Comment: Impossible, it may work. I don't like this empty tags, but it should work perfectly. You are missing some details

Comment: I've used your code and place the label tag outside of the to row tag and it seems to work

Comment: look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/
Pull the window wide to view the result as a full page

Answer (score 2):

you can also apply margin-top css style to div which contains those buttons.

```
<style>    
   .margin_top_25 {
       margin-top:25px;
    }
</style>

<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label >Client</label>
    <Select class="form-control" >
      <option>Client 1</option>
      <option>Client 2</option>
      <option>Client 3</option>
      <option>Client 4</option>
      <option>Client 5</option>
      <option>Client 6</option>
    </Select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 margin_top_25">
    <button type=submit class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Add </button>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-4 margin_top_25">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info pull-right" vertical-align="bottom"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>  Get Data </button> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a table instead and vertical align your tds :

```
<table>
  <tr class="row">
   <td class="col-md-4"><label >Client</label>
    <Select class="form-control" >
      <option>Client 1</option>
      <option>Client 2</option>
      <option>Client 3</option>
      <option>Client 4</option>
      <option>Client 5</option>
      <option>Client 6</option>
    </Select>
   </td>
   <td class="col-md-4">
     <button type=submit class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa      fa-dot-circle-o"></i> Add </button>
   </td>
   <td class="col-md-4">
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-info pull-right"  vertical-align="bottom"><i class="fa fa-dot-circle-o"></i>  Get Data </button> 
   </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And then :

```
td{
 vertical-align:bottom
}
```

Note : This is not an absolute solution.Tweak your css and html to get the exact layout , but this should align your elements as desired.

Comment: Tables are not responsive.. and i guess for two inputs, table implementation isn't good approach

Answer (score 0):

You can do this alignment by using flex-box. I have attached a plunker I created. If you have any questions then please let me know.

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/tTgLGJMbeHb2l33lCiOT?p=preview)

```
.form-group {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.client-label {
  margin-left: 40%;
  font-size: 3vw;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: teal;
}

.add-button {
  width: 100px;
}

.data-button {
  width: 100px;
}

div.form-group {
  width: 50%;
  margin-left: 25%;
}

.buttons {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Thanks!